# css width % working incorrectly; longer than necessary

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width

I have a set of images that I want stacked one over the other. I am working with bootstrap, and I kept a parent div at the center of a jumbotron. This div encloses an image, and absolutely divs which further contain images. However, when I apply `width:100%` to the child divs, they end up being longer/

This js-fiddle is the code snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/yhL6tndn/

I am led to believe that % is actually measured with respect to parent container (`#major` in the example). So the width and height of my `#semimajor` should be equal, since width and height of `#major` are equal.

On checking actual sizes, I find that either

1. the entire width of the the parent of `#major` is being used to calculate  width of `#semimajor`

or

2. the width of `#major`is being calculated with margins. My `box-sizing` properties are set to `border-box`.

What should happen is that the `#semimajor` should measure 150px by 150px. I cannot spot error in the code though.

Edit 1: `position: relative` on `#major` removes the issue, but I still do not understand why this must be the case.

Comment: `position: relative` defines a new ancestral containing block for absolutely positioned elements. `#semimajor` is set to `position: absolute`, so it's closest ancestral containing block if there is no relatively positioned element parents, will be the document itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used `position: absolute`, it comes out of the normal flow of the document and is positioned with respect to `body` and comes out of `#major`.

Notice when you have added `position: relative`, it is positioned absolutely to the nearest relatively positioned parent container i.e. `#major`, so the child divs don't go past the `#major`.

Comment: Why would you answer a question like this and not vote to close as a simple error? This has been discussed many times before on Stack Overflow and in its current state, will not be useful to very many users. And you're just reiterating information posted in the comments. If anything you could have written a much better explanation than this.

Comment: Please check the timing of the answer and comment. I am sure we were typing at the same time. I didn't notice the comment was posted.

Comment: Your answer was posted a full minute after my comment, and you haven't explained why you would answer a simple error question instead of voting to close as such. The whole point is to allow questions like this to be cleaned up by the roomba

Comment: *Edit 1: position: relative on #major removes the issue, but **I still do not understand why this must be the case.***

Comment: Ok, but that still does not explain why you've chosen to answer a simple error question instead of providing the very small amount of relevant information in a comment then voting to close as such.

Comment: Voted to close. Can't delete this answer unless OP marks it unsolved.

Comment: As long as this answer does not get an upvote in the next 9 days then this question will be cleaned up. Otherwise it will stick around forever.